# How to know if a record has been modified or included new in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe in which new rows can be included, but I have to know if that new row that enters on the dataframe is a modification of some existing record, or if on the contrary, it is a new record.

For example, Input dataframe:

| A | B | Population | Start | End | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 250 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 350 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 125 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |

We can see that row 1 is a modification of row 0, noting that the timestamp is higher and apart from the dates and the pop value are modified.

Expected Output:

| A | B | Population | Population_prev | Start | Start_prev | End | End_prev | Type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 250 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | Mod | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 350 | NaN | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 125 | NaN | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |

Thank!

Comment: Are there colunms that allow to uniquely identify your rows? `A` and `B` maybe?

Comment: How do you "include" new rows? Or is it the question?

Comment: @Cimbali Correct, column A is the general group and column B is a subgroup of A. So there will only be one combination of A + B

Comment: @Giacomo That's the question, how can a get the Expected Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you sort by timestamp, and use `groupby` on your columns that define unique rows, you can get all the information you want. Using [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to get the last row in each group, and [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) to get the second-to-last:

```
>>> groups = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby(['A', 'B'])
>>> groups.last()
         Population                 Start                   End            timestamp
A   B                                                                               
A1  B1          100  2021-05-15 00:00:00   2021-06-30 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00
A2  B3          350  2021-05-10 00:00:00   2021-05-12 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00
    B4          125  2021-06-02 00:00:00   2021-06-04 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00
>>> groups.nth(-2)
A1  B1          250  2021-05-30 00:00:00   2021-06-02 00:00:00   2021-06-06 00:00:00
```

Now all these dataframes are indexed on columns `A` and `B` so you can simply [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with an added suffix, reset the index, and you’re done:

```
>>> mod = groups.last().join(groups.nth(-2), rsuffix='_prev').reset_index()
>>> mod
     A    B  Population                 Start                   End            timestamp  Population_prev            Start_prev              End_prev       timestamp_prev
0  A1   B1          100  2021-05-15 00:00:00   2021-06-30 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00            250.0  2021-05-30 00:00:00   2021-06-02 00:00:00   2021-06-06 00:00:00
1  A2   B3          350  2021-05-10 00:00:00   2021-05-12 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00              NaN                   NaN                   NaN                  NaN
2  A2   B4          125  2021-06-02 00:00:00   2021-06-04 00:00:00   2021-07-06 00:00:00              NaN                   NaN                   NaN                  NaN
```

Then some details to make it look like what you have:

```
>>> col_order = [
...     *df.columns[:2],
...     *(new_col for col in df.columns[2:-1] for new_col in [col, f'{col}_prev']),
...     'type', 'timestamp'
... ]
>>> row_type = mod['timestamp_prev'].isna().map({True: 'New', False: 'Mod'})
>>> mod.join(row_type.rename('type')).reindex(col_order, axis='columns')
     A    B  Population  Population_prev                 Start            Start_prev                   End              End_prev type            timestamp
0  A1   B1          100            250.0  2021-05-15 00:00:00   2021-05-30 00:00:00   2021-06-30 00:00:00   2021-06-02 00:00:00   Mod  2021-07-06 00:00:00
1  A2   B3          350              NaN  2021-05-10 00:00:00                    NaN  2021-05-12 00:00:00                    NaN  New  2021-07-06 00:00:00
2  A2   B4          125              NaN  2021-06-02 00:00:00                    NaN  2021-06-04 00:00:00                    NaN  New  2021-07-06 00:00:00
```

---

An alternate technique that works with any number of duplicate values is to use `pivot`. Let’s use the same groupby but with [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to define the order of columns:

```
>>> num = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount().rename('num')
>>> num
1    0
0    1
2    0
3    0
Name: num, dtype: int64
>>> pvt = df.join(num).pivot(index=['A', 'B'], columns='num', values=['Population', 'Start', 'End'])
>>> pvt
      Population                     Start                                       End                     
num            0    1                    0                    1                    0                    1
A  B                                                                                                     
A1 B1        250  100  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00  2021-06-02 00:00:00  2021-06-30 00:00:00
A2 B3        350  NaN  2021-05-10 00:00:00                  NaN  2021-05-12 00:00:00                  NaN
   B4        125  NaN  2021-06-02 00:00:00                  NaN  2021-06-04 00:00:00                  NaN
```

As you can see that gives you what you want but with a multi-index in columns.  Let’s flatten that to normal columns and we’re done:

```
>>> pvt.columns = [f'{col}_prev{n if n > 1 else ""}' if n > 0 else col for col, n in pvt.columns]
>>> pvt.reset_index()
    A   B Population Population_prev                Start           Start_prev                  End             End_prev
0  A1  B1        250             100  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00  2021-06-02 00:00:00  2021-06-30 00:00:00
1  A2  B3        350             NaN  2021-05-10 00:00:00                  NaN  2021-05-12 00:00:00                  NaN
2  A2  B4        125             NaN  2021-06-02 00:00:00                  NaN  2021-06-04 00:00:00                  NaN
```

Comment: One question: If the same group A2 + B4 has two new entries, how can I make it take both? because it only takes one of the two. For example, they were two different time intervals, I want to take both since they would be considered two new additions.

Comment: @GBM you'll need a lot of columns them. But you can get `.nth(-3)` and so on until `groups.size().max()`

Comment: I’ve added a way that works with any number of columns @GBM, and a little simpler than doing a loop on `.nth()`